# c++ operator overloading, destructor is called

Tags: c++, parameters, operator-overloading, destructor

I am trying to track how many object is created of a given class. If I overload the operator ++ in the class, the destructor is called but I don't know why. To be more specific:

```
class num{
public:
    virtual void setValue(int)=0;
    static int db;
    num(){}
    ~num(){}
};

int num::db = 0;

class int32: public num{
public:
    // GET
    int getValue();

    // SET
    void setValue(int f);

    // constructor
    int32()
    {
        cout << "Construction..."<<endl;
        this->value = 0;num::db++;
    }

    // destructor
    ~int32()
    {
        cout << "destruction..."<<endl;
        num::db--;
    }

    // operators
    int32 operator++(int);
    int32 operator++(void);

protected:
    int value;
};

int32 int32::operator ++()
{
    this->value++;
    return *this;
}

int32 int32::operator ++(int)
{
    this->value++;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    int32 i;
    i.setValue(20);

    cout << (i++).getValue()<<endl;
    cout << (++i).getValue()<<endl;

    cout << num::db;

    cout << endl << "End of execution.";
    return 1;
}
```

The result is:
Construction...
21
destruction...
22
destruction...
-1
End of execution.destruction...

So after ++i and i++ a destructor is called, but why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's because an instance of the class is copied before `i++` and `++i`, since that can then be assigned elsewhere. Because you're not assigning it, it gets destroyed. I'm actually pulling at straws though, so I'd be interested to see the answer,.

Comment: I would suggest you implement the copy constructor with a cout which should point you to the reason.

Comment: Still I don't think you get `++i` and `i++` right...

Comment: >>Still I don't think you get ++i and i++ right... You might be right, i am now learning operator overloading.

Comment: If you're just learning operator overloading, don't start with `++`.  It has some additional subtilities that the other operators don't (like distinguishing pre- and postfix forms).  And if you do, the prefix forms should return a reference (conventionally, at least), and the postfix form should return a copy with the old value.  (Both of yours return a copy with the new value.)

Comment: I might add that _most_ operators only work well with value semantics.  Which don't work well with polymorphism.  So your base class could be a design error.  (There are ways of making it work, but they aren't that easy, and they generally imply a lot of extra runtime overhead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you return *a copy*. You would want to create a *copy constructor*.

Comment: I created a copy constructor that increases num::db, now it contains correct number at the end of execution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a copy of the object in the ++ operator.

each time you call `return *this` you actually create a copy of the object which is passed to the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your "operator++()" methods both return a copy of a "int32". Thus for every call a new instance is created and returned.